# Custom validator form control value retains the previously added value even after deleting the field- Angular

Tags: angular, customvalidator

I have a income field and a delete icon besides it. I can add and delete the field from UI using another dropdown field. I am using custom validator to validate income field.The problem here is, once i added the income field and entered a value to it( say, 1) and then deleting it using delete icon, the  updated value( which is now '') of income field after deleting the field is not getting passed to custom validator formcontrol. As aresult, the validation fails. Below is the code.

home.component.html:

```
 <app-income-field placeholder="Business income" [value]="userInputs.incomeInfo.businessIncome"
              type="number" name="businessIncome" (textValue)="getTextValue($event, 'businessIncome')"
              [showDeleteIcon]="true" [parentForm]="additional_info_form" (deleteIncomeField)="deleteIncomeField(1)">
            </app-income-field>

home.component.ts:

  buildFormGroup(): void {
businessIncome: new FormControl(this.userInputs.incomeInfo.businessIncome)
}

getTextValue(event, fieldname) {
if (event == 0) {
      event = "";
    }
    switch (fieldname) {
  case 'businessIncome':
        this.userInputs.incomeInfo.businessIncome = event;
        break;
}
}
Custom validator:
export class SalaryIncomeValidation {
static SalaryIncomePattern(AC: AbstractControl) {
 const businessIncome = (AC.get('businessIncome').value);  // after the deleting the field and again adding it back still retains the previously added value.
}
}
```

Comment: Where are you using SalaryIncomePattern method?

Comment: it is a custom validator which is referred in HTML

Comment: @Chellappanவ thats how i am using ..my question is not about how to use custom validator, it is about the deleted value from UI is not getting updated to FormControl.